# databind entityframework ObjectSet<T> to a gridcontrol (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using DevExpress `EntityInstantFeedbackSource` as datasource to an `XtraGrid` control. However I am not using the connection string from the `app.config` file; rather I am setting the connection string for entity framework at runtime.
The code is given below:

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    entityInstantFeedbackSource1.KeyExpression = "Prodid";
    entityInstantFeedbackSource1.GetQueryable += entityInstantFeedbackSource1_GetQueryable;
    entityInstantFeedbackSource1.DismissQueryable += entityInstantFeedbackSource1_DismissQueryable;
    gridControl1.DataSource = null;
    gridControl1.DataSource = entityInstantFeedbackSource1;
}
void entityInstantFeedbackSource1_GetQueryable(object sender, GetQueryableEventArgs e)
{
    EntityConnectionStringBuilder ecsb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
    ecsb.Metadata = @"res://*/Model2.csdl|res://*/Model2.ssdl|res://*/Model2.msl";
    ecsb.Provider = @"System.Data.SqlClient";
    ecsb.ProviderConnectionString = @"data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=AdventureWorks;  integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
    using (var context = new ObjectContext(ecsb.ConnectionString))
    {
        context.DefaultContainerName = "AdventureWorksEntities";
        ObjectSet<Person> query = context.CreateObjectSet<Person>();
        var q = from s in query
               select s;
        e.QueryableSource = q;
        e.Tag = context;
    }
}

void entityInstantFeedbackSource1_DismissQueryable(object sender, GetQueryableEventArgs   e)
{
    ((ObjectContext)e.Tag).Dispose();
}
```

The grid is blank. However if I write a foreach loop around 'query' and view the output in `Console.WriteLine` then I can see the data.
Also if I set `e.QueryableSource = q.ToArray().AsQueryable()` then I can see data in the grid. But doing this will load all data at one time there by nullifying the benefit of `EntityInstantFeedbackSource`.

Why there is no data in query? And how to databind ObjectSet to a gridcontrol?

Comment: however if I set e.QueryableSource=q.ToArray().AsQueryable() then i can see data in the grid. But doing this will load all data at one time thereby nullifying the benefit of entityinstantfeedbacksource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason of this issue is that you are disposing the `ObjectContext` directly in `GetQueryable` handler rather then to do it in `DismissQueryable` only. Moreover you can pass the resulting object set directly to `e.QuerableSource`.
Thus the correct code should looks like this:

```
void entityInstantFeedbackSource_GetQueryable(object sender, DevExpress.Data.Linq.GetQueryableEventArgs e) {
    //... connection initialization ...
    var context = new ObjectContext(ecsb.ConnectionString);
    ObjectSet<Person> personSet = context.CreateObjectSet<Person>();
    e.QueryableSource = personSet;
    e.Tag = context;
}
void entityInstantFeedbackSource_DismissQueryable(object sender, DevExpress.Data.Linq.GetQueryableEventArgs e) {
    ((ObjectContext)e.Tag).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: however there is one little problem. If i replace SQL Server for VistDB and try to group by any column in the grid i get inconsistent results. Grouping is fine for SQL SERVER. Also it is fine for XPInstantFeedbackSource instead of entityInstantFeedbackSource

Comment: I believe the guys from [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) knows the answer...

Comment: Ya, you are right. If I don't use any of the instantfeedbacksources and databind the grid directly to the entity then grouping is not a problem.